# R, Shiny, custom error messages

Tags: r, shiny

When there is an error in R, there is usually a red error message shown in the dashboard. 
[image]

Is there a way to define custom error messages and trigger errors in the server code?

Comment: @agstudy: no, I want to display a custom error message, due to some event in the server logic.

Answer (score 0):

```
R CMD BATCH "yourRcode.R" >> logfile.log
```

That way you get a log file from your process called "logfile.log"

Comment: should serve my purpose, I'll give it a try